# Git log with only the folder names and sorted

Tags: git, git-log

I am trying to get a list (one list and not per commit) of the files that were modified/added from a specific tag until now.

I did this:

```
git log TAGNAME..HEAD --oneline --pretty=format: --name-only
```

Then it gave me a list with a blank line between the commits and grouped by each commit. like that:

```
M       AFolder/x.xml 
M       BFolder/1.cs

M       AFolder/Q.cs
```

Is there any way that I can get 1 list, not grouped+sorted alphabetically with the files that were changed ? like:

```
M       AFolder/Q.cs
M       AFolder/x.xml 
M       BFolder/1.cs
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it
Adding | sort to the end of the line.